Jetson Orin NX Problems in booting the system
I have Jetson Orin NX 8GB.
I connect this to an power adapter with 12V 3A.
In the initial state when the system is completely cooled down, there is no problem in booting the system with the power. However, whenever I run something on the system, and try to reboot it, my jetson won't turn back on until it is fully cooled down. It takes at least 30 minutes for it to turn back on.
When I reboot, it turns on for a second (I can tell it by its fan running), but it powers down like it is not connected to OS (installed in m.2 ssd).
Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong? I thought it was the issue of system throttling and heating issue but the temperature seems okay to me while I'm running some program because it maintains around 45 degrees celsius.
I tried to reboot my jetson orin nx after running some program, but it won't turn back on until it is completely cooled down.

The issue you're describing may be related to insufficient power supply. While a 12V 3A power adapter might be adequate for a cold start, it may not meet the instantaneous power requirements when restarting after the system has been running for a while.
Try using a 12V 5A or higher-powered adapter to ensure sufficient power supply .
